# Trying to return a promise from an action creator dispatched from mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I have an action creator like so.

```
export const register = user => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestRegistation());
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Axios.post(make_url('/users'), { user: user }).then(response => {
        if (response.data.errors) {
          reject(response.data.errors);
        }
        if (response.data.user) {
          resolve(response.data.user);
        }
      });
    });
  };
};
```

and I have a form like so.

```
handleSubmit: (values, props) => {
  props.props.register(values).then(
    response => {
      console.debug('response', response);
    },
    errors => {
      console.debug('errors', error);
    },
  );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    register: user => {
      dispatch(register(user));
    },
  };
};
```

It would look as if I'm not returning a promise as I see this.

```
signup.js:186 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

signup.js:186 is relative to `props.props.register(values).then(`

I fell like I'm close but I'm not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try removing the function body `{}` from your props function. `register: user => dispatch(register(user))` to make it implicitly return the promise. You are not returning anything from that function right now.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Awesome! thank you!, that was it. @Tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the promise from the `register` function in `mapDispatchToProps`. You can remove the function body to make the return implicit, or add a `return` statement.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    register: user => dispatch(register(user)),
  };
};
```